# cartesian product while getting data from three tables

Tags: mysql

There are three tables

- master_table (`item_id`, `item_name`)
- details(`availability`, `item_id`)
- price(`price`, `item_id`)

I want to get `item_name`, `availability` and `price` based on `item_id` which is present in master

```
SELECT 
    rawmaster.item_name, 
    rawdetails.expiry_date,
    rawdetails.batch_sequence_num, 
    rawdetails.available_qty
FROM master_rawitem_t rawmaster 
INNER JOIN rawitem_details_t rawdetails 
ON rawmaster.item_id=rawdetails.item_id 
INNER JOIN rawitem_price_t rawprice 
ON rawdetails.item_id=rawprice.item_id;
```

But I am getting a Cartesian Product.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are getting Cartesian product; are you saying that because you are getting more than one row per item_id?

Presumably, item_id is the primary key for the master_table. What are the primary keys of the other two tables? Because you have only joined on item_id, if their PKs are **not just** item_id (which I presume they are not, else you could have all this data in one table) then having more than one row with the same item_id in either of the other two tables will give multiple rows per item_id.

Comment: the primary key of other two tables are auto generated sir

Comment: Did you want to expand on that? What are the primary keys of those other two tables?

Comment: master_table (item_id(pk), item_name)
details(id(pk),availability, item_id)
price(id(pk),price, item_id)...the id is auto generated ...sir i think this will helpfull to you

Comment: Because those ids in the detail tables bear no relation to the original item_id it is possible to have duplicate records for price and availability which will give you multiple results for each item_id when joined. 

Unless it is valid to simply use the latest record in the details tables (**and also that there is a way of identifying that latest record**) you are a bit stuck and should consider altering the database design.

Perhaps if those detail table IDs are sequential, you might use the largest ID for each item_id? If so and you need help with altering the SQL to use that, let me know.

Comment: sir ..now i am maintaining details_id(pk) in price table and my price will look like   price(id(pk),price,item_id,details_id(pk)) with this i am working now ...is this crrt way sir?

Comment: Perhaps we should go back to what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to to have **one price** for each item and **one availablity** value for each item? What you have said so far implies that this is so. In that case, it's far simpler to have ONE table and have the price and availability in the "mater table".